# bootstrap off canvas menu collapse on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I'm using this Off Canvas menu which I found to be really easy and simple to get working. [Off Canvas menu](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/) One area that I am struggling with is how to get the men to collapse once one of the off canvas links is clicked. Right now I have this, and it works, but as soon as the menu slides off it, instantly appears again.

```
    $(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function () {
    console.log("toggle");
    $("#myNavmenu a").offcanvas("hide")
});
```

Here is my html:

```
    <div id="burgerWrapper">
             <nav id="myNavmenu" class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left offcanvas" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">INTRO</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LOCAL COURT MATTERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SECTION 32 APPLICATIONS</a></li>
                 </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target="#myNavmenu" data-canvas="body">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You may have another event bound to that element. Try `$.unbind()`:

```
    $(".navbar-toggle").unbind().on("click", function () {
        console.log("toggle");
        $("#myNavmenu a").offcanvas("hide");
    });
```